# Need to change capital character to a small one in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have this string where I need to make some characters capital so I use that `UpCase` command... But what if I need to make small character from capital one? What do I use in that case?

Comment: Kind of depends. Which version of Delphi? How is the text encoded? How do you want to handle locale?

Comment: I am using Delphi 7, text is in the textfile in classic sentences and I dont understand your last question.. And no it's not LowerCase command, because LowerCase command requires string input, but I need to do it with single characters.

Comment: Don't worry. Delphi can implicitly handle that for you. You are free to pass `Char` to a function with a `string` parameter.

Comment: @TLama That's true but it it feels wasteful to perform multiple heap allocations just to add 32 to an integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UpCase` is not locale aware and only handles the 26 letters of the English language. If that is really all you need then you can create equivalent `LoCase` functions like this:

```
function LoCase(ch: AnsiChar): AnsiChar; overload;
begin
  case ch of
  'A'..'Z':
    Result := AnsiChar(Ord(ch) + Ord('a')-Ord('A'));
  else
    Result := ch;
  end;
end;

function LoCase(ch: WideChar): WideChar; overload;
begin
  case ch of
  'A'..'Z':
    Result := WideChar(Ord(ch) + Ord('a')-Ord('A'));
  else
    Result := ch;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: yes its all I need but there really isnt anything more simple ? Cause I will be needin it on an Exam where I have 20 minutes to write a code.

Comment: How would you suggest making this more simple? I cannot see any complexity here at all. The fact that you need this in an exam is your problem. What's more, if you have additional constraints on acceptable solutions, shouldn't they appear in the question? Feel free to omit the `WideChar` overload if you won't call it.

Comment: what is AnsiChar ? and Widechar

Comment: In Delphi 7, `Char` is an alias for `AnsiChar`. `AnsiChar` is an 8 bit character type, typically used to hold text encoded in the active code page. However, sometimes `AnsiChar` is used to hold text in other 8 bit encodeds, for instance UTF-8. `WideChar` is a 16 bit character type that holds text encoded in UTF-16. In Delphi 2009 and later, Unicode Delphis, `Char` is an alias to `WideChar`.

Comment: ok thanks...and what is overload ? (that is my last question).

Comment: Overloaded procedures are where you have multiple procedures with the same name. The compiler then chooses which one to call based on the types of the parameters that you pass.

Comment: Are you still struggling with this problem? Do you need more help?

Answer (score 1):

You should learn how to find the solution on your own, not how to use Google or stackoverflow :)

You have the source of the UpCase function in System.pas. Take a look at how it works. All this does is subtract 32 from the lower case characters. If you want the opposite, add 32 instead of subtracting it. The Delphi help will tell you what `Dec` or `Inc` does.

```
var
  S: string;
  I: Integer;
begin
  S := 'ABCd';

  for I := 1 to Length(S) do
    if S[I] in ['A'..'Z'] then  // if you know that input is upper case, you could skip this line
      Inc(S[I], 32); // this line converts to lower case
end;
```